# How to get MD5 checksum from artifactory in Linux command line

Tags: python, linux, md5, artifactory, md5sum

[image]I have to get the MD5 checksum from the artifactory link:

www.artifactory_company_link/artifactory/webapp/#/artifacts/browse/tree/General/abc.html

I have tried CURL -I artifactory_link. But didn't get the MD5 checksum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the MD5 checksum from command line, you need to use the [Artifactory File Info REST API](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-FileInfo).

So the proper way to get your file's MD5 checksum would be (assuming the `General` repository here)

```
curl -s -u<user>:<password> www.artifactory_company_link/artifactory/api/storage/General/abc.html
```

This will output a big json output of the file's info, including its MD5 checksum.
Use `jq` to get just the checksum

```
curl -s -u<user>:<password> www.artifactory_company_link/artifactory/api/storage/General/abc.html | jq ".checksums.md5"
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. By using above command i am facing "parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 2, column 0" issue

Comment: Which of the two? Did you follow the instructions in the REST API docs?

Comment: Second one. Now i got null as output. I have added the screenshot in the question

Comment: Do you have a repository called `General`? If not, use the actual repository name your file is stored in. Try running without the `jq` first and see the full output.

Comment: When i try to run without jq. I got error "Authentication is required"

Comment: Ah... right. You need to add the `-u<user>:<password>` to the command. I added to my answer.